Getting key codes on key up independent of keyboard layout
I'm implementing a Perkins Braille input emulation for a specialized piece of software.
TL;DR: A Braille character consists of up to eight dots which, when entered from a QWERTY keyboard, produce Unicode Braille. The layout is as follows (for historical reasons, see the Wikipedia article about Braille typewriters):

f, d, s, a for dots 1, 2, 3, 7, and
j, k, l, ; for dots 4, 5, 6, 8.

So, when a user presses one or more keys simultaneously and releases them (it's important!), a Unicode Braille pattern is produced.
As users have varying dexterity (some of them have deep problems with pressing keys quickly and/or simultaneously), it became a tradition among hardware and software manufacturers to process the Braille character on key up. So, for example, you can press dot 1, think a little (without releasing it), then press dot 2, then think again, then press dot 3, then release dot 3 (because you are mistaken), press dot 4 and release everything — dots 1-2-4 should be entered as a result.
The Problem
We use KeyEventArgs.KeyCode. Everything works great if the keyboard layout is English or something other than Latin (tested with Cyrillic so far). However, if we try keyboards with remapped main row such as French (which swaps Q and A, and also has M where English semicolon is)or German and Spanish (which have ö and ñ in place of the semicolon respectively), it stops working because well, the key code is wrong.
I tried digging into the problem to use P/Invoke, but actually the problem is that I don't know what to do. I can get the character from the virtual key code, but it wouldn't help me because okay, I know it's Q, not A, and so?
So my question is: what data should I get and how can I get it so that:

It is gettable on key up;
It is independent of the remapped keyboard layouts, like: the key where English A is, no matter, is it an A, a Q, an infinity sign or whatever else.


If you handle WM_KEYUP (also applies to WM_KEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYDOWN, WM_SYSKEYUP of course), in lParam you get the keyboard's scancode (e.g., uint keyScancode = (m.lParam >> 16) & 0xff; uint extendedState = (m.lParam >> 24) & 0x1;)). The scancodes represent the key pressed before it's translated to generate WM_CHAR messages, i.e., don't depend on the keyboard layout specific to a language, only the hardware layout (IIRC, 4 main groups, ISO105 is the standard one). So, for example, scancode 27 maps to the US/UK ; char, while it maps to the German ö and Spanish ñ

Keyboard Layout Info -- See the Scan code mapper for keyboards section in here: Configuration of keyboard and mouse class drivers -- You can also register to receive Raw Input, to handle WM_INPUT messages instead
